# Ivy setup with Git?

Tags: git, ivy

I've used [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) with SVN to manage dependencies for Actionscript projects in the past. The library I used was [ivysvn](http://code.google.com/p/ivysvn/).

It seemed to work pretty well, the svn repository hosted versioned binary .swc files for each Actionscript library and I would pull them down into individual projects using ivysvn ANT tasks.

Is there a similar workflow like this for git? I'm guessing it might be a little more complicated (maybe using git submodules) since git can't really pull down individual files as far as I know. I'd also probably need another ANT task specific to git like the third party ivysvn libary. Is there a better way to manage 3rd party dependencies with git besides ivy?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use a repository manager like Nexus instead of abusing a SCM to manage binary artifacts.

Comment: Or Artifactory - nicer for Ivy, in my opinion.

Comment: If someone asks a question, we cannot lecture them not to ask their question if they have valid need to do so.

Answer (score -1):

I actually blogged about this [a year ago](http://ben.straubnet.net/post/735737032/git-for-other-purposes). I hope it helps you.

Comment: If someone asks a question, we cannot lecture them not to ask their question if they have valid need to do so.